# button click event is not working in asp.net mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have asp button **(in mvc4)** and i want to execute server side code on button click event (**using ASPX view Engine**) but click event is not working. My code is in Index.aspx like

```
 <script runat="server">

    Protected Sub BtSend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)


        text_mess.Value = Nothing
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, [GetType](), "showalert", "alert('Message Sent');", True)
    End Sub
</script>

<textarea id="text_mess"  runat="server" name="text_mess" draggable="false">
 Message
</textarea>
<br />
<asp:Button CssClass="login-submit" ID="BtSend" runat="server" Text="Send"
 OnClick="BtSend_Click"  />
```

Comment: What is the type of the page? ASPX page or cshtml page? take in consideration that MVC has a different way on handling routes from asp.net webforms.

Comment: Its in ASPX View Engine..

Comment: I Have exactly the same problem. Have you find any solution yet?